# About CompleteRequest();

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.0, response.redirect

I'm using `Response.Redirect(url, **false**);` in order to prevent an exception. However, I have seen it recommended to use `CompleteRequest();` after it, and I don't understand that. Example: [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  .  As far as I know, `CompleteRequest` will **not** terminate the execution (though it will affect rendering) so any code with persisting consequences such as database writes - *will* have an effect. And therefore stopping the code must be managed by a `return` etc. And it is **not** needed for the `Redirect` to process.

Is my understanding correct? (I'm asking because of the link above and similar ones.)

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct. Using `CompleteRequest()` signals the ASP.NET runtime that no further processing on the request is needed and it bypasses all the events in the HTTP pipeline and directly calls the `EndRequest` event. However, it won't stop executing the the remaining lines of code. It would just end the request gracefully in order to prevent data loss.